# java.io.IOException: Remotely closed in gatling

Tags: scala, stress-testing, gatling

I have recorded scala script using gatling recorder; but when I run it, it starts showing  `java.io.IOException: Remotely` closed error
Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

That's probably not a Gatling issue, but a real error with your server forcefully closing the connection while Gatling is writing on it.

It could be that your server cannot withstand the load and aggressively closes random connections, or some misconfiguration in some network component.

Comment: But here I have made single transaction, where-in 
1. user login 
2. view some page 
3. logs out

Comment: Which version of Gatling do you use? Can you share a reproducer?

Comment: Please upgrade to 2.0.3